# Change requestor of a task

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2010, tasks

*(I don't have the English version of Outlook therefore some translations maybe aren't accurate.)*

Is it possible to change the "requestor" of an Outlook task? When somebody assigns me a task by telephone e.g., I create an Outlook task manually. Then, the "Organisation" is automatically set to my name and I can't change it.

I don't want to use any "free text field" for this if possible, but only a field, where only persons from the address book are allowed.